# Internet access for SSRS reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to get my company to start using SSRS for reporting but I realized something today that I have never tried to use SSRS outside the local LAN before.  Our application is external facing on the internet and if I implemented SSRS, I would need to be able to access the Report Manager via an external URL.

It is setup and configured currently, but I can only use it locally on the company domain.  I tried searching the web for how to configure this and what best practice is but I didn't really get anywhere.

I imagine it would not be good to set it up on the same server that the database is hosted on?  Has anyone done this before?  I have setup one application that was inherently not meant to be external before to be external and it was a pain in the ass. :D  Course, that application had to be proxied through Tomcat to IIS.

We have a developed an intranet web application build on ASP.Net MVC 4 and SSRS 2012, which is live for past 2 years.

Now we planning to host the same in internet. We are having a bottle neck now for SSRS. As SSRS web access is not ready to use externally (internet). 
I also checked for SSRS custom authentication which again not much recommended by Microsoft!

We are looking for something like a proxy (web application) to the SSRS web access, which can be hosted as a web application in IIS along with other services.

Is there any ready to use references / tools available.

**Update : For better understanding** 
We are rendering the ssrs reports inside the Asp.Net mvc razor views using iframe.
And also we are using ssrs for export to various formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ReportViewer control to hide the SSRS from the internet.

The connection to the SSRS is from your web servers, not from the internet

Comment: We are rendering the ssrs reports inside the Asp.Net mvc razor views using iframe.
And also we are using ssrs for export to various formats.

Comment: am searching for some proxy like solution .. .

Comment: We are planning for ReportViewer control, as we didn't found any other solution. Thanks !